# What is an unsigned int in c?

Tags: c, variables

I have some code that I have to study and I'm not understanding what is a unsigned int and how it works.

```
void print_all_sums(unsigned int n,double a[n])
{ // 1 <= n <= 30
   unsigned int i,j,mask;
   double s;
```

Something like this.

Comment: Did you try Googling it?

Comment: You did not show how that `unsigned int` is used. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: You use it like you would any other value. Just that it with be either 0 or a positive number.

Comment: It represents what in mathematics is known as a "Natural Number". 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/

Answer (score -1):

An `unsigned int` in C is a data type which has a non-negative value. (Eg. 0,1,2,3,4...)

Comment: 0 is also a valid value, but is not positive.

Comment: I tried it in a simple code and 0 works as unsigned int. Thanks for the help @AntonH.